# Why does /login?logout redirect to /login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my Spring project, I set the logout target url to "/login?logout" to display the login page with a message "You are now logged out".

In the Spring Security config, I did this :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
}
```

And the logoutSuccessHandler :

```
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (authentication != null) {
        Log.debug(authentication.getName() + " LOGOUT !!");
    }

    setDefaultTargetUrl("/login?logout");
    super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);       
}
```

When I try to logout, I arrive on the page "/login" (without the ?logout).
I don't understand why it redirects me on this page.

I think the application is trying to redirect me on "/login?logout", but since I'm no longer connected, Spring security wants me to log in again.

When I try to access the "/login?logout" page while I am logged in, it displays the good page.

I found a solution to this problem by adding this :

```
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/error","/login").permitAll()
```

Why didn't `loginPage("/login").permitAll()` do this?
Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Why doesn't** `loginPage("/login").permitAll()` **allow access to** `/login?logout`**?**

Because when you do `permitAll` on a `FormLoginConfigurer`, or most other configurers for that matter, it will only allow access to those [exact URLs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.3.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/PermitAllSupport.java#L36).

**Well, why does** `authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()` **allow access then?**

Because that uses an `AntPathRequestMatcher`, which [matches on the request path only](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.3.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.java#L148), and the path [does not contain the query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Understanding_URLs#Basics.3A_anatomy_of_a_URL).

**But I know I've seen code that lets me access** `/login?logout` **without any explicit** `permitAll` **at all.  What's up with that?**

Spring Security likes providing "sensible" defaults, and it thinks it's "sensible" to provide default login and logout pages if none are specified.  The default logout page is `/login?logout`, so you get to use it if you specify nothing.  This is done by a `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` which auto-generates some HTML and [short-circuits URL authorization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.3.RELEASE/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java#L159).

**So why do I lose access to the default** `/login?logout` **page when I specify a** `logoutSuccessHandler`**?**

When you specify your own `logoutSuccessHandler` or `logoutSuccessUrl`, Spring Security assumes you are providing your own logout views, so it doesn't initialize the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` to short-circuit URL authorization on the logout page, and expects you to configure authorization on your own views yourself.

**But I want to keep the default logout page.  I just want to add some custom extra handling.  Can't I just do that?**

If you want to specify your own `logoutSuccessHandler` but still keep the default `/login?logout` view, you have to tell the `DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` to still keep providing it.  You can do this with a custom [`SecurityConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.0.3.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/SecurityConfigurer.java), as follows:

```
.logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
.and()
.apply(new SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {
    @Override public void configure(HttpSecurity builder) throws Exception {
        builder.getSharedObject(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class).setLogoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
    }
})
```

Comment: Most excellent - I had managed to elucidate most of this by crawling through the code but I was missing `SecurityConfigurerAdapter`.  Thanks for your answer and we'll see about the bounty in a couple of days.

Comment: Okay - but there is a Catch 22! If one sets a custom handler, Spring _resets_ the URL. If one sets a custom URL, Spring resets the handler. So, whilst the `SecurityConfigurerAdapter` is useful; there is not (unless I'm missing something) a way to have a custom, say, failure handler, and have Spring autoconfigure the `permitAll` correctly, Further, the `ExactUrlRequestMatcher` used is `private` so one cannot even do something analogous manually...

Comment: The API is terribly fragile, but I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for.  Can you post your broken code and I'll try to address it as a mini-question?  Also please specify if you're trying to use `DefaultLoginPageConfigurer` or you have your own view templates.

Comment: Thanks for your detailled answer. It helps to understand why it works like this.

Comment: @heenenee that's okay - your answer explained the process logic. My comment was more to say that `setLogoutSuccessUrl` will work fine; but, for example `setFailureUrl` will **unset** any custom failure handler that may have been set - so you cannot have the default behaviour of allowing the exact failure URL and a custom handler (even if it happens to extend the default handler). It would seem that this is all left well enough alone and event handlers used instead - which comes with it's own can of worms (yey, threading).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Correct, using `failureUrl` in conjunction with a custom `failureHandler` will not work.  The best way to handle that scenario would be to subclass `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, override `onAuthenticationFailure`, and use that as your `failureHandler`.  Overall though, when you add something with this API, you risk breaking something else.  I think the design of a fluent API for security configuration is a bit of a mismatch.